# Else Statement for Null Variable

Tags: javascript

I have this javscript that I wrote, and I want the "else" event to happen when bgimage does not equal 7.  I have looked into this issue and am unclear about how to check if the variable is null or not defined.  Currently, when bgimage does not equal 7, the Firebug just says "bgimage is not defined."

Thanks for teaching me how to do this in advance.

```
if (bgimage == 7)
{
document.writeln("\n<img src='/v/vspfiles/templates/donnell/images/Company/services_bg.jpg' id='bg' />");
}
else
{
showImage();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to create a DOM node, fill in the attributes and then append it the element you want it placed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `bgimage` has not been declared with `var` in the current or higher scope (or assigned a value as a global variable without `var`) when you use it in an `if` statement you will get that error. You can test for that as follows:

```
if (typeof bgimage === "undefined") {
    // hasn't been declared, or is set to undefined
    // do something
} else if (bgimage == 7) {
    // etc
```

Or test in one line:

```
if (typeof bgimage != "undefined" && bgimage == 7) {
```

Comment: thanks to all who helped.  I'll post an answer to my question when it lets me with the code I ended up using!

Answer (score 2):

Check the type of the variable to determine if it is undefined:

```
if (typeof bgimage != 'undefined' && bgimage == 7)
```

Comment: is it also ok to use `if(bgimage && bgimage == 7)` ?

Comment: @JohnKalberer - No, not if you want to test for variables that haven't been declared at all. If there is a `var bgimage` statement in the current or higher scope then `if(bgimage && ...)` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a variable is undefined by using `typeof`, then combine that with your original condition:

```
if (typeof(bgimage) != "undefined" && bgimage == 7)
```

So now the `else` section of your code will be used if bgimage is undefined, or if it is defined, but not equal to 7.